# Python idiom for '... if ... else ...' expression

Tags: python, idioms

How to write the expression shorter:

```
return '%.0f' % float_var if float_var else float_var
```

or

```
if float_var:
    return formatted_string
else:
    return None
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Shorter"?  Your first example is obviously "shorter".  Why are you asking which is shorter?  Are you asking for a third example which is magically even shorter?  Since your question shows which is shorter, it's not clear what you need to know.

Comment: The two examples aren't even the same code.  Aside from the obvious (one apparently pre-calculates "formatted_string" in some unshown fashion), the second one returns `None` where the first returns `float_var`, which might be `None`, or `False`, or `0.0`, or a few other things...  Who upvotes these things anyway?

Comment: @Peter Hansen: Good question.  I can't even interpret the question and it's already got upvotes.  I wish the upvoters would leave some "+1..." comments on why the question is so cool.

Comment: @Peter Hansen, @S. Lott: Interpreting StackOverflow questions is more of an art than a science. for my answer below, I interpreted this one to mean, "I know two ways of writing an if-else ternary condition. Is there a shorter way? When should I use either one?"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The expression `<value> if <condition> else <other_value>` is pretty idiomatic already -- certainly more so than the other example, and is probably preferred whenever `<value>` is simple. This is Python's ternary operator, so if you were looking for something like `<condition> ? <value> : <other_value>`, that doesn't exist.

If computing `<value>` or `<other_value>` takes a few steps, use the longer `if: ... else: ...` alternative.

Comment: assuming you're in 2.5 onward.

Comment: @Gregg: Hopefully that's the case -- otherwise you're using 2.4 or earlier, which means your version of Python is at least 6 years old!

Comment: Check out Centos5, and other server distros, John.  There is still plenty of 2.4 in the wild, ugh!

Answer (score 6):

I would use brackets to make the expression more readable:

```
return ('%.0f' % float_var) if float_var else float_var
```

When I first saw it I read it as

```
return '%.0f' % (float_var if float_var else float_var)
```

which would be silly. I had to try it out to make sure which way it worked.

BTW Your first example not equivalent to your second example

```
if float_var:
    return formatted_string
else:
    return None
```

This will always return either a formatted string or None.  Your first example if you pass in anything that evaluates to False (False, 0, 0.0, "", [] etc) will return that unchanged, so your return type could be string, boolean, list, int, float etc.  This is probably not what you want, especially if 0.0 is a legitimate value for float_var.  I would change your code to:

```
return ('%.0f' % float_var) if isinstance(float_var, float) else None
```

alternatively:

```
try:
    return "%.0f" % float_var
except TypeError:
    return None
```

which will work for other integers (and longs) by converting them to float.

Comment: @Dave, mostly good, though with that final alternative note that `"%.0f" % False` would return `"0"`, which might be undesirable too.

Comment: @Peter - good point, I forgot about the automatic conversion of True/False to 1/0.

Comment: The typecheck for `float` is always a warning sign. If the two classes of expected values are numbers and `None`, it makes a lot more sense to check `is not None` than `isinstance(foo, float)`, since the former still allows the operation to be duck typed.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not clear what exactly you want to do.

  1. The most literal interpretation would have it work like this

     ```
     >>> float_var = 4.5
     >>> '%.0f' % float_var if float_var else float_var
     '5' # This is a string
     >>> float_var = 0.0
     >>> '%.0f' % float_var if float_var else float_var
     0.0 # This is a float
     ```

     which I am almost certain you did not want.
  2. I guess you are wanting to check for `None` with "`if float_var`"? If so, you always spell it "`if foo is not None`", not "`if foo`", the former being clearer and less bug-prone.

     If that *is* what you intended, I suggest you revise your model. Propagating errors by repeatedly returning `None` is a bad thing: it is ugly and bug-prone and non-idiomatic. Use exceptions instead.
- Shorter is not always better. Your snippets are not painfully long or unwieldly. In fact, you will want to make them a little *longer* if you use them to avoid a potential bug.

  - Someone may suggest abusing the short-circuiting behavior of `or` for this. However, this makes code harder to read and doesn't allow you to specify between `None` and other false values, which often leads to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using are already using `v if c else u` you are already using the most readable and efficient ternary operator.

There are [other ways](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/programming/#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) but they suffer in readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
float_var and "%.0f" % float_vav
```

Isn't it awesome?

Comment: Nope:

>>> f=0.0

>>> x=f and "%f" % f

>>> type(x)

<type 'float'>

>>> f=0.1

>>> x=f and "%f" % f

>>> type(x)

<type 'str'>

... If the value is 0.0, you get a float, otherwise a string.

Comment: I have some mixed feelings about this. It's kind of awesome. As far as I understand it is logically equivalent to
'%.0f' % float_var if float_var else float_var

But I would not use it in my code. I think it's difficult to read. May be it's only because this trick is not idiomatic to python and I have never seen it before. No, no, no, I will never write like this! But I am impressed.